# Build a regular grammar for a regular language

Tags: regular-language

The language is an infinite set of chains that are defined by the next conditions.

Conditions:

```
1) The language chains may consist of symbols from the set {1,a,b}. 
2) The language chains always start from subchain '1a'.
3) Every languange chain has to include at least one subchain 'aa'.
```

For example:

```
1aa, 1abaa, 1aaab, 1aab1a, ... etc.
```

The regular expression in formal language seems to be like this: 1a ((1+b)* a)* (a (1+b)*)* a (1+b+a)*

**What will the correct regular grammar be for this language?**

I've thought of many ways but it seems to be too complex for me. This solution isn't correct too, I guess.

```
G ({1,a,b}, {A,S}, P, S)
P:
S -> 1S|bS|aA
A -> 1A|bA|1a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression should be easier than you're making it; what about: 1a (1+a+b)* aa (1+a+b)*

Given this, the regular grammar is also not too bad:

```
S := 1R
R := aT
T := 1T
T := bT
T := aU
U := 1T
U := bT
U := aV
V := 1V
V := aV
V := bV
V := 1
V := a
V := b
```

Something like that ought to do it, if I didn't make a silly mistake.